# How to add navigation-support to a capsule

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want to add a [navigation-support](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/navigation-support) model to my capsule.

I can't figure out how to add it from the Bixby Studio, and I don't know what the filename should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The file needs to be in the `resources` folder, and named `something.navigation.bxb`.